# React Quill supported image file formats

Tags: express, react-quill

I am trying to validate a message that a user creates using react quill from my express server, but I am not sure what file formats react quill supports.

Currently, my code checks all the images for these image extensions:

```
const allowedImageExtensions = ['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'svg'];
```

However, I am not sure if this is the full list. Does anyone know where I can find the full list of supported file formats?